# When I make the window small the scroll bar sticks

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you make your window smaller the the left sidebar gets in the way and the whole page just becomes a big mess. I am aiming for the left sidebar to scroll when overflown but I dont want it to stick when you scroll on the regular page.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this problem but I cant seem to figure it out. I am new to most coding languages so that is probably why. I am expecting for the left scroll bar not to stick when I scroll on the main page. I also want the sidebar to scroll when it is overflown

`

```
<body onload="checkForName()">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#test" id="nameOfCompany"> My Paper Company</a>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#donate">Donate</a>
      <div class="flexcolumn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftmain" class="leftmain">
    <p id="button" div="leftmain" onclick='show("htpmain")'> How To Play</p>
  </div>
  <center>
  <div id=htpmain class="main">
    <div class="toptext">
      <h1>
         How To Play
      </h1>
      <p>This guide will get you start the game and will be helpful to grasp everything you need to do.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" />
  </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

```
function checkForName() {
  let name = localStorage.getItem("storageName");
  if (name != "" && name != null) {
    alert("Welcome again " + name);
    console.log("User Relogged")
    document.getElementById("nameOfCompany").innerHTML = " " + name + "'s Paper Company";
  } else {
    name = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (name != "" && name != null) {
      localStorage.setItem("storageName", name);
      console.log("Registered New User")
      document.getElementById("nameOfCompany").innerHTML = " " + name + "'s Paper Company";
    }
  }
}

function hide(item) {
  document.getElementById(item).hidden = true
}

function show(item) {
  document.getElementById(item).hidden = false
}

hide("htpmain")
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 345px;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toptext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.toptext h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #404040;
}

.toptext p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #404040;
}

.flexcolumn {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.leftmain {
  height: 100%;
  width: 325px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #333333;
  align-content: center;
}

.leftmain p {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 300px;
}

.leftmain p:hover {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-content: center;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Are you using HTML 4 or less? Because the `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: Could you convert this into a snippet to try it?

Comment: This is why hamburgers were created. The general practice is to hide the sidebar when the page gets too small and make the user click on some hideous icon to show it again. It's a pretty unavoidable problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `.leftmain` class, you have specified a width of `325px`, and it will not change its pixel width no matter what size your screen resolution is.

```
.leftmain {
   width: 325px;
}
```

There are many different ways to specify screen width aside from pixel count. For example, a percentage of 25% will always take up 25% of the width, no matter what your resolution is.

```
.leftmain {
   width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which browser you're using, because I do not see that problem in Chrome or Firefox, but this code may help you.

```
/***** Styling Scrollbars *****/


/*** For Firefox ***/

:root {
  scrollbar-width: thin; /* Width of Scrollbar (works with both Vertical and Horizontal bars) */
}

/*** For Other Browsers | When doing it this way, you cannot style one part of it without specifying all of it ***/

/* Width of Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px; /* For Vertical Scrollbar */
  height: 6px; /* For Horizontal Scrollbar */
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: Whitesmoke; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 76%);
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: Gray; 
}
```

It makes the scrollbar smaller. The non-Firefox way is more cumbersome, but also more manipulatable. Hope it can help  (or that I can understand more ).